# How to unite two similar functions into one function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have two similar function that work perfectly. But I would like to unit them into one function. Please, I need your help. Thank you!

Function 1

```
(defun  read_char_into_list (&aux (list nil)) 
    (setq char                     ; link this variable with open the file
        (open "fichier-char.txt"     ; open the file
            :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error)) 
    (loop 
        (cond 
            ((not (setq line (read-line char nil nil))) (return)) 
            ((push (read-from-string line) list)) ) ) 
    (close char)    
    (reverse list) )  

(read_char_into_list) ==> (... e è é ê ë F f ...)
```

Function 2

```
(defun  read_code_into_list (&aux (list nil)) 
    (setq code 
        (open "fichier-code.txt" 
            :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error)) 
    (loop 
        (cond 
            ((not (setq line (read-line code nil nil))) (return)) 
            ((push (read-from-string line) list)) ) ) 
    (close code)    
    (reverse list) ) 

(read_code_into_list) ==> (...65 192 194 196 198 ...)
```

Function united

```
(defun  read-into-list (fichier &aux (list nil) )
    (setq fichier 'code or 'char)  
    (setq code
        (open (string-concat "alphabet_"   (string 'code)  ".txt")
            :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error)
    (setq char
        (open (string-concat "alphabet_"   (string 'char)  ".txt")
            :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error) ) 
    (loop
        (cond
            ((not (setq line (read-line (or code char) nil nil)))        (return))  
            ((push (read-from-string line) list)) ) )
    (close code) 
    (close char)   
    (reverse list) ) )

(read-into-list 'code) ==> should give (...65 192 194 196 198 ...)
(read-into-list 'char) ==> should give (... e è é ê ë F f ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, the difference between the two functions is only in the
name of the file they read from, so all you need to do is pass the name
of the file to the function:

```
(defun read-into-list (file-name)
  (with-open-file (in file-name) ; :direction defaults to :input
    (loop :for line = (read-line in nil nil)
      :while line
      :collect (read-from-string line))))
```

and call it as

```
(read-into-list "fichier-char.txt")
```

or

```
(read-into-list "fichier-code.txt")
```

To comply to your calling requirements, you can do

```
(defun read-into-list-1 (what)
  (read-into-list (concatenate 'string "fichier-" (string what) ".txt")))
```

Note that [`string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_string.htm) will probably return [an upper-case string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_ab.htm):

```
(string 'code)
==> "CODE"
```

Note also that [`with-open-file`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_open.htm) ensures that the file is closed even when there is an error, e.g., in [`read-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm).

Comment: Thank you sds for interesting to my case. I have the obligation to keep the same structure and to call the function like this: (read-into-list 'code) or (read-into-list 'char)

Comment: @user3653521 If `fichier` is your parameter, you can use the filename `(if (eq fichier 'char) "fichier-char.txt" "fichier-code.txt")`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out how. My problem was how to select what file to open. I just mention it by a condition, the first one: if variable = 'code, then open this file, if variable = 'char, then open that file. It was all.

Thank you for trying to help me, maybe next time you will.